# NAnt exec command garbling output

Tags: npm, nant

When I execute a batch file that calls npm from the command line I see nicely formatted output, such as:

```
├── interpret@0.3.10
├── pretty-hrtime@0.2.2
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@1.0.0
├── minimist@1.1.0
├── tildify@1.0.0 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── semver@4.2.0
├── v8flags@1.0.8
├── chalk@0.5.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.2, ansi-styles@1.1.0, support
├── orchestrator@0.3.7 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-
├── liftoff@0.13.6 (extend@1.3.0, flagged-respawn@0.3.1, resolve@1.0.0,
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.13 (graceful-fs@3.0.5, mkdirp@0.5.0, vinyl@0.4.6, defa
└── gulp-util@3.0.2 (object-assign@2.0.0, array-differ@1.0.0, array-uni
gh2@0.6.3, multipipe@0.1.2, lodash.template@2.4.1, dateformat@1.0.11)
```

However, when I call the same batch file from a NAnt script, using the exec task, the output becomes garbled (even if I use the "output" switch to pipe output to a file):

```
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ pretty-hrtime@0.2.2
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ interpret@0.3.10
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ deprecated@0.0.1
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ archy@1.0.0
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ minimist@1.1.0
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ tildify@1.0.0 (user-home@1.1.1)
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ chalk@0.5.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.2, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ semver@4.2.0
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ v8flags@1.0.8
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ orchestrator@0.3.7 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.1.5)
 [exec] Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ liftoff@0.13.6 (extend@1.3.0, flagged-respawn@0.3.1, resolve@1.0.0, findup-sync@0.1.3)
 [exec] ÔööÔöÇÔöÇ vinyl-fs@0.3.13 (graceful-fs@3.0.5, strip-bom@1.0.0, defaults@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.6, mkdirp@0.5.0, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6, t
h2@0.6.3)
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: What happens if you use the `output` parameter on the `exec` task to pipe the output directly to a file?

Comment: Thanks @JamesThorpe, good point. Tested, and it behaves the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the internals of the NAnt `exec` task not setting an encoding on the StandardOutput stream reader.  I have replicated the behaviour with my own console app.

The method in question is here: https://github.com/nant/nant/blob/master/src/NAnt.Core/Tasks/ExternalProgramBase.cs#L511

What's missing is a way to set the encoding on the `ProcessStartInfo`, such as:

```
StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
```

The only workaround I can see (short of submitting a pull request to Nant) is to write a custom task.  It's as simple as this:

```
[TaskName("customexec")]
public class CustomExecTask : ExecTask
{
    protected override void PrepareProcess(Process process)
    {
        base.PrepareProcess(process);
        process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        process.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    }
}
```

I've struggled to load my custom task any other way than using the [loadtasks](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/loadtasks.html) task, however.

Comment: Nice find.  May be worth seeing if there's a bug open for it already, if not open a new one.  The developer responded to and created a fix for [another issue](https://github.com/nant/nant/issues/84) that came up on SO recently.